# Makefile pattern rule targets for pattern part

Tags: makefile

Is there a way to have a parameterized Makefile target. I'm trying to use wildcards but I cannot seem to make it work.

The problem is that I just want the **%** part. Since I need to generate some paths.

```
bin/bootstrap.ino.bin: bin/
    $(ARDUINO_BUILDER) $(BUILD_FLAGS) bootstrap/bootstrap.ino

bin/sensorscan.ino.bin: bin/
    $(ARDUINO_BUILDER) $(BUILD_FLAGS) sensorscan/sensorscan.ino

bin/httpprober.ino.bin: bin/
    $(ARDUINO_BUILDER) $(BUILD_FLAGS) httpprober/httpprober.ino
```

To something like:

```
bin/%.ino.bin: bin/
    $(ARDUINO_BUILDER) $(BUILD_FLAGS) %/%.ino
```

Answer (score 2):

The automatic variable `$*` expands to the stem of the target ("the pattern part").  See [Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) in the GNU make manual.